# Eclipse Birt - How to group dimensions in data cube

Tags: eclipse, report, tableau-api, birt

Eclipse Birt - How to group dimensions in data cube?

I am trying to group dimensions in data cube and insert a sub total row based on ONE single dimension. However, I am not able to find an option to group the dimensions. And, the sub total row is applied to each record not a group.